# matlab animation with multiple layers

Tags: matlab, animation, alpha, contourf

I'm using contourf to generate a wave propagation animation. I'm coloring just one range in the matrix for each iteration of the for loop.I'm then animating the generating images as gif. 
When I add an image to to serve as background to my wave animation the animation preserves all the colored ranges as the animation progresses.

Here' part of the code

```
filename = 'heart18a.gif'; 
img = imread('heart_18.jpg');
 min_x = 0;
max_x = 661;
min_y = 0;
max_y = 749;
%plot the background and Z points
hold on
for n = min(z):1:max(z),
 imagesc([min_x max_x], [min_y max_y],img);
 plot(x,y,'.');
end
hold off
 i = 1;



  %loop and isomap generation
for n =1:1:14,    

hold on   
      contourf(XI,YI,ZI,[n n+1],'linecolor','black')

      colormap (jet)
      caxis ([-10 50])
      alpha(0.5);
%set the y-axis back to normal.
%set(gca,'ydir','normal');
hold off

      drawnow

      frame = getframe(1);


      im = frame2im(frame);

      [imind,cm] = rgb2ind(im,256);

      if i == 1;

          imwrite(imind,cm,filename,'gif', 'Loopcount',inf);

      else

          imwrite(imind,cm,filename,'gif','WriteMode','append');

      end
      i = i + 1;

end
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Also what are `x`, `y` and `z` in your code?

Comment: my question is that how do I keep just one range painted while I'm also displaying the background.

Comment: x and y are axes, z is the color value of the recording.

Comment: sorry. and ZI XI and ZI are interpolated values of the entire grid

Comment: Post a minimal, _runnable_ example